# PyQt5 setText with a signal class

Tags: python, signals, pyqt5, settext, qlineedit

I'm trying to update QLineEdit() with setText.

However, that is made through a signal thread class (A)
that is able to send every time signal to a widget class (B) [**deputy to change the text**].

let see an example:

```
classB(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(classB, self).__init__(parent)
    self.lineLayout = QGridLayout()
    self.textbox    = QLineEdit("")
    self.lineLayout.addWidget(self.textbox, 0, 0)
    self.setLayout(self.lineLayout)

def setInt(self,intVal):
    # The shell displays this value perfectly
    print(intVal)
    # it does not display the change in QWidget that lives in  MainWidget
    self.textbox.setText("val: " + str(intVal))

def paintEvent(self, event):    
    painter = QPainter()
    painter.begin(self)
```

While the class A's code:

```
classA(QThread):
sendVal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
def __init__(self,serial):
    QThread.__init__(self)

    def do_stuff(self):
        cont = 0
        while True:
          self.sendVal(cont)
          cont += 1
```

So we connect the signal:

```
class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
     getClassA = classA()
     getClassB = classB()

     getClassA.sendVal.connect(getClassB.setInt)
```

I have observed the following behaviors:

1. The int signal is perfectly received within the [**setInt**] function of class B;
2. The real problem is that everything that happens inside the setInt function stays in setInt. I can not even change a hypothetical class variable (In def init of classB)

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].